# How to hide div after page refresh or click browser back button

Tags: javascript, html, popup, hide, show-hide

I have popup code below and I want to show this popup for per-user, only one time even with a page refresh or visiting another site.

I tried some code but it isn't working for me.

```html
<div id="popup">
     <div id="close">&times;</div>
MY CONTENT
    </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    setTimeout(
        function open(event){
            document.querySelector("#popup").style.display = "block";
        },
        0000 
    )
});


document.querySelector("#close").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.querySelector(".popup").style.display = "none";
});
    </script>
```

Comment: Use localStorage or cookies to store values on future page loads. If you want to show once per tab/session, use sessionStorage.

Answer (score 0):

Use a cookie to remember.

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    //check if cookie exists. 
    if (!document.cookie.includes("popup")) {
        setTimeout(
            function open(event){
                document.querySelector("#popup").style.display = "block";
                //set cookie since it didn't exist previously
                document.cookie = "popup=true" 
            },
            0000 
    })
});


document.querySelector("#close").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.querySelector(".popup").style.display = "none";
});
```

Comment: Hello, I used this code. Cleared browser history and open page again. But not loading popup. Is there any problem with code? or do you have any other solution? Thank you.

Comment: Hello, I changed my code. I meant to include a '!' before checking for the cookie. Let me know if that works.

Comment: @GüngörArslantaş did you try this? This works for me. Let me know if you need additional help.

Answer (score 0):

I think using localstorage will do the trick.  It won't work here cause stack doesn't allow localstorage

```js
if(localStorage.getItem('closeMe') == 'yes')document.getElementById("popup").classList.add("closeMe");

document.querySelector("#close").addEventListener("click", function(){
localStorage.setItem('closeMe', 'yes');
if(localStorage.getItem('closeMe') == 'yes')document.getElementById("popup").classList.add("closeMe");
    


});
```

```css
.closeMe{
   display:none;
   }
```

```html
<div id="popup">
     <div id="close">&times;</div>
MY CONTENT
    </div>
```